Static path in Express Js is working in local system but not working in Remote server
I am new in Express js/ Node. I build my website using these environment and set the path for static content. The above said static path is working fine in the local system. But static path is not working on remote server. Here is my code for mentioning static path:
const staticPath =path.join(__dirname,"public");
const templatedPath = path.join(__dirname, 'templates/views');
const partialPath = path.join(__dirname, 'templates/partials');
const port = process.env.PORT || 8000;

hbs.registerPartials(partialPath)

app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
app.set('views', templatedPath);
app.use(express.static(staticPath));
app.use('/vsoft/static', express.static(staticPath));

My static path
 <link href="/vsoft/static/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

Above path is working fine local system for all url, but in our hosting server this path is not working.
Please help me to resolve this issue
